# C++, reading multiple numbers from single input line

Tags: c++

I have written an app in C++ which expects two lines at input. First input tells how big an array of int will be and the second input contains values separated by space. For example, the following input

```
5
1 2 3 4 99
```

create an array containing `{1, 2, 3, 4, 99}`

What is the fastest way to do so? I have tried to create a dynamic memory array to store it but I don't know how to read multiple numbers without looping through the whole string checking if it's space or a number?

so I want it to store all the number in one line instead of

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
{
   cin >> arr[i];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `What is the fastest way`? `store all the number in one line` [of code]? What do you really want? Speed is not a real issue here, using only one line of code is **never** a real issue. I would have thought that what you really want is a simple way to make the code do what you want. And what you have written already does that.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to take the second line as an input using `getline`, and use `stringstream` to parse it to your list/array/vector of numbers:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ifstream>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::stringstream;
using std::vector;
using std::ifstream;

int main() {
    ifstream file("input.txt");
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    stringstream ss(line);

    int number;
    vector <int> numberList;
    while (ss >> number) {
        numberList.push_back(number); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally have found the simplest thing to do is to read the entire line into a string.  Then call `strtok()` from the C++ standard library to tokenize the integers (as strings) followed by `stoi()` to convert from string to integer.  You can then append each integer to an `std::vector` if you don't know ahead of time how many there are.  HTH.

All of the methods that I mentioned above are well documented here: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Answer (score 1):

Take the input of the second line as `string` using `getline` in c++, like:

```
string arr;
getline(cin, arr);  // getline will take the whole line with the spaces
```

after that you can use `stringstream` which is a builtin function in c++ to split the numbers as you said they are separated with space. The whole code will look like :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string arr;
    getline(cin, arr);

    stringstream ss(arr);
    int value;
     
    while(ss >> value){
       cout << value << " "; // your desired numbers in value, you can store these values in a vector or array
    }
}
```